# How not to lock a resource for long for write operation in a micro-service environment?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, queue, locking, microservices

I have a microservice A which basically supports CRUD operations on resources (Imagine them to be like data stores). I have a microservice B which uses A to write certain objects to a resource. This process of writing involves two steps.

1. B calls A via HTTP request to create an object called writeObject with some additional details (Like to which resource, B wants to copy its objects). Microservice A creates this writeobject and adds it to a Queue. B polls this Queue and fetches these writeobjects and does some validation of its own. But before it starts its validation process, it sets a lock on the resource so that no other writeObject is processed and copied to the same resource.
2. After completing the validation successfully, B again calls A via HTTP request to finally copy objects to the resource. A processes the request and copies the objects as specified by the writeObject to the resource and releases the lock.

So my question is, if B takes too long to do the validation, other writeObjects in the queue which are trying to write to the same resource will have to wait for very long. How can this process be mitigated or avoided ? What steps can be taken ?

Answer (score 0):

With distributed locks, it's generally a good idea to have them expire after a duration. It's hard to guarantee that service B will *always* complete each request. It could crash and forget that it was in the middle of a transaction, or suffer a storage failure, etc. These are special cases of a slow transaction (ones that may never complete). Putting an expiration on locks creates an upper limit for how long any other request will have to wait in the presence of a slow transaction.

The way this would work is:

1. B calls A to create the writeObject request and claim the lock.
2. A would set the expiration time for that lock based on the expected maximum duration for the validation and copy request.
3. C tries to call A to claim the lock itself.
4. A would check: has the lock claimed by B expired? If not, C waits until the lock is released or expired.
5. If B issues its copy request before the lock expires, it completes normally and the lock is released to C.
6. If B does not issue the copy request before the lock expires, A gives it to C.
7. If B then issues the copy request after the lock has expired, this request fails. B can choose to either start over with a new validation process, reclaiming the lock once it's available again, or accept the failure and handle it another way (logging it, propagating it to its own caller, etc).

In the case where service B is consistently slower than the expiration duration, it might not ever be able to complete its transaction. This is referred to as "resource starvation". You can improve this by allowing it to keep its expired lock if no other service has tried to claim it, but if a resource is under high contention, slower services might always lose out. This approach can still cause a bottleneck if there are a lot of slow transactions. Setting the expiration time can be a tricky balance between not wanting to have a high expiration rate vs. not wanting to have a long wait time.

There are some other approaches you can take with different tradeoffs.

## Optimistic locking

Optimistic locking uses version tracking on the resource to minimize the duration of locking:

1. When B fetches the writeObject data from the queue, the message includes the current version of the resource that it's writing to.
2. B performs its validation *without* claiming a lock on the resource.
3. When it submits the final copy request, it includes the version number in the request.
4. A only needs to lock the resource for the duration of this copy request. It checks that the current version of the resource is the same as the version in the request. If so, it completes successfully and increments the version.

In a scenario with two concurrent writers, assuming that the version field starts as 1:

1. B creates a writeObject request.
2. C creates a writeObject request for the same resource.
3. B reads its writeObject from the queue, containing version 1.
4. C reads its writeObject from the queue. It also contains version 1.
5. B & C concurrently perform their validation.
6. C completes validation first, and submits the copy request with version 1.
7. A completes the copy and increments the resource's version to 2.
8. B submits its copy request with version 1.
9. A sees that the resource version is greater than the version in the request, and rejects the request.

The benefit of this approach is that fast transactions don't have to wait for slow transactions at all. It simplifies the handling of locks. The drawback is that it can make resource starvation worse. A slow service may never be able to complete its writes before a faster one comes along and preempts it. It also increases the prevalence of failures for resources under high contention. The application will need to be designed to handle these as common events rather than exceptional conditions.

## Merging

An even better solution is to avoid locking entirely by merging the results of concurrent requests. This is very dependent on the use case and data model, so it isn't always possible, but when it is, it can provide a very scalable solution with no waiting required. In this scenario, requests from B and C would both be allowed unless A detects a conflict. This can mean decomposing the requests to a resource to see which specific fields are updated, and allowing concurrent requests to distinct sets of fields. In the best case, you can use a data structure like a [Conflict-Free Replicated Data Type (CRDT)](https://crdt.tech), which allows concurrent updates to be consistently merged.